# Maximize the value of $\sqrt{x-x^2}+\sqrt{cx-x^2}$ without using calculus

Tags: optimization, triangles, radicals, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Assume that $c$ is positive. How can we maximize the value of $\sqrt{x-x^2}+\sqrt{cx-x^2}$ with respect to $x$ without the use of calculus?

With calculus, we can easily find out that the max of the expression is when $x=\frac{c}{c+1}$.

My attempt to the question is consider the expression as the distance between points. Below is the figure.
[image: triangle]
The question becomes finding the longest length of the red line. However, I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

$$
\left(\sqrt{x-x^2}+\sqrt{c x-x^2}\right)^2\le \left(x+1-x\right)\left(x+c-x\right) = c
$$

then

$$
\sqrt{x-x^2}+\sqrt{c x-x^2}\le\sqrt{c}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\frac{c}{c+1}t.$

Thus, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sqrt{x-x^2}+\sqrt{cx-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{c}}{c+1}\sqrt{t(c+1-ct)}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{c+1}\sqrt{ct(c+1-t)}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{\sqrt{c}}{c+1}\left(\frac{t+c+1-ct}{2}+\frac{ct+c+1-t}{2}\right)=\sqrt{c}.$$
THe equality occurs for $t=1$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks again for you kind support during the suspension time. If you are interested I've raised a related discussion [HERE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29254/505767). Cheers

Comment: Hi @gimusi . I really don't like discussions in Meta. In my opinion this a place, where a limited number of users, which are destroying this site, trying to get a legitimation to do it.

Comment: I think that open discussion are the only way to find a compromise between different point of views. Thanks again. Bye

Comment: Nice approach but somewhat cheating to take $x=\frac{c}{c+1}t$ at the beginning.

Comment: @Wss Because we know that the equality occurs for $x=\frac{c}{c +1}$ and it would be much more better if it will happen for some variable is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $$\sqrt{x-x^2}+\sqrt{cx-x^2}\le \sqrt{c}$$
Squaring we get

$$2\sqrt{x-x^2}\sqrt{cx-x^2}\le 2x^2-x-cx+c$$
squaring again and factorizing we get $$(cx-c+x)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.
Remark: We can only square the inequality if $$2x^2-x(c+1)+c\geq 0$$ this is true if $$0<c\le 1$$ for $$0\le x\le c$$ or $$c>1$$ and $$0\le x\le 1$$

Comment: @Sonnhard I think the right side of your second inequality can be negative. At least, you need to prove that it's not negative.

Comment: This is true, the condition is complicated.

Comment: @Sonnhard But $c^2-6c+1$ can be positive, which says that the right side can be negative. No?

Comment: Yes with the inequalities $$x-x^2\geq 0$$ and$$ cx-x^2\geq 0$$ it simplifies to the given above

Comment: @Sonnhard But how did you got it? By the way, there is a very nice proof that $2x^2-(c+1)x+1>0$. Try to find it.